# CMake file RENAME and create directories if not existing

Tags: cmake

What I want to do is `file(RENAME from/a/dir/some_code a/new/dir/some_code)` while the directories `a`, `a/new`, and `a/new/dir` are not existing.

[The file RENAME API](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#rename) says nothing about this and testing it shows it can't create new directories while renaming.

`file WRITE` has this functionality, but not RENAME :/ However, I don't think it is applicable here since I want to move files and directories.

Comment: You could create the needed directory with the explicit call to [file(MAKE_DIRECTORY)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#make-directory) before performing `file(RENAME)`.

Comment: MAKE_DIRECTORY takes <directories>. As I said In my use case I want to move *files* and directories.

Comment: You need to only prepare a directory for the "base" destination file, which you pass to `file(RENAME)`. That is, with preliminary `file(MAKE_DIRECTORY a/new/dir)` following `file(RENAME from/a/dir/some_code a/new/dir/some_code)` will work whenever `some_code` is a file or directory with inner files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tsyvarev's helpful comments, here is a snippet to generate non-existing directories before moving a file or directory:

```
set(p "file/or/directory/to_move")
set(target "a/new/dir")

# create a variable subdir and set it to the immediate parent directory's path.
get_filename_component(subdir ${p} DIRECTORY)
# in this case subdir is "file/or/directory".

# create all the in-between directories from base path to target path.
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY a/new/dir/${subdir})
# in this case it will create "a/new/dir/file/or/directory"

file(RENAME ${p} a/new/dir/${p})
# to_move is present in "a/new/dir/file/or/directory/to_move"
```

Documentation of [get_filename_component](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_filename_component.html)

Comment: `get_filename_component` has been deprecated for the sake of `cmake_path`.